# Send Jenkins console output as HTML email

Tags: html, email, jenkins, build, jenkins-plugins

I don't know if this is at all possible but still asking here to see if anyone has tried/thought about it.

I have a build running that when fails echo out html code as given below. I want to send this html as an email to all the recipients.

Currently when I use the simple email plugin then the whole console output is sent as an email which contains all these html tags (not at all readable). Then I installed the Email Ext plugin but I am not sure if the pre-send script can read my console output and send email. Has anyone tried it? Is it worth spending time on it or should I just modify the output to display formatted text?

This build is for internal tools and I can't create a .html file or send the link to the .html file as email because the path is behind firewall.

I don't know if this is supported at all but is it possible that the console output shows html output?

Thanks for the help!

```html
                <style type="text/css">
                    table.gridtable {
                    font-family: verdana,arial,sans-serif;
                        font-size:11px;
                        color:#333333;
                        border-width: 1px;
                        border-color: #666666;
                        border-collapse: collapse;
                    }
                    table.gridtable th {
                    border-width: 1px;
                        padding: 8px;
                        border-style: solid;
                        border-color: #666666;
                        background-color: #dedede;
                    }
                    table.gridtable td {
                    border-width: 1px;
                        padding: 8px;
                        border-style: solid;
                        border-color: #666666;
                        background-color: #ffffff;
                    }
                </style>

                <table class="gridtable">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                          <th>Service Checked</th>
                          <th>Status</th>
                          <th>Response</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                          <td>canary</td>
                          <td>Success</td>
                          <td>Please override the check() method</td>
                        </tr>

                        <tr>
                          <td style="color: red;"><strong>www.mysite.com</strong></td>
                          <td style="color: red;">Failure</td>
                          <td>Ping to https://www.mysite.com/canary?from=here FAILED</td>
                        </tr></tbody></table>
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Email Ext plugin works just fine with HTML. It's up to your email client to parse HTML (but then again, most these days do).

The question is: how does your build output this HTML above? Does it output it to file? Does it display it in Console Output?

If the text is in console output, use:

`<pre>${BUILD_LOG_EXCERPT, start="Regex-for-start", end="Regex-for-end"}</pre>`

The `<pre>` tags are to preserve spacing/formatting.
The `start` and `end` regular expressions are to identify the "starting line" from which to start displaying log, and the "ending line" at which to stop displaying log.

Note that the `start` and `end` lines themselves are excluded. So, in your build, put a header and footer lines just before and just after your html output, and use them here.

For reference, in the email-ext configuration, click the **Content Reference** question mark icon <kbd>?</kbd>

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. My build output this html in the Console Output. I will try your suggested method now!

Comment: So I tried with your example in the pre-send script but its giving me a weird exception. I put this in my pre-send block: `${BUILD_LOG_EXCERPT, start="\\b(start-here)\\b", end="\\b(end-here)\\b"}` and my test php script is printing those two before and after the html but I am getting `org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
Script1.groovy: 1: unexpected token: < @ line 1, column 1.
   <html><body><table border=1>
   ^
1 error`

Comment: No no... that goes into the body of email, in `Default Content`, not `pre-send`

Answer (score 7):

So this is how I solved it with the help of [@Slav](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1720943/slav).

Jenkins job was running this script:

```
<?php
echo "start-here\n";
echo "<html><body><table border=1>
<tr><td>yello1111</td><td>11111bbbbbbb</td></tr>
<tr><td>yelloooo</td><td>bbbbbbb</td></tr>
</table></body></html>";
echo "end-here\n";
```

The job was configured with [email-ext](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Email-ext+plugin) and in the **Add post-build action->Editable Email Notification -> Default Content** I put the following:

```
${BUILD_LOG_EXCERPT, start="\\b(start-here)\\b", end="\\b(end-here)\\b"}
```

This send the email as html content and not the text of html.

Answer (score 7):

Go to "Manage-jenkins"->"configure system"
Than on the "Extended E-mail Notification" settings, put the below line in "default content" text-area

```
<pre>${BUILD_LOG, maxLines=9999, escapeHtml=false}</pre>
```

Comment: Is required maxLines=9999 ? if I will not used then what is drawback of this?

Answer (score 1):

[email-ext](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Email-ext+plugin) plugin works pretty well for me. Give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

Even if you are behind a firewall, you should be able to write an HTML file to the workspace (from your script).
This file you can then send as/include in the mail body using
`${FILE,path="PATH"}`.